# Resize event from another Class inherited from QWindow in QT

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt5

I am writing a simple program (**C++**, **QT**, **QML**) in which I want to implement `resizeEvent` and then andujst the window height and width using some pattern. My problem is that when I am resizing the window, `resizeEvent` is not called. I think that I`m doing something really wrong, but I am not sure what is it. Any ideas will be appreciated.

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    QObject *root = engine.rootObjects().first();
    class CMaze maze(root,&engine);
    return app.exec();
}
```

CMaze.h

```
class CMaze: public QWindow
{
public:
    CMaze(QObject *root, QQmlApplicationEngine *engine);
private:
    QObject *root;
    QQmlApplicationEngine *engine;
    /*+ Some other variables*/
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
};
```

CMaze.cpp

```
CMaze::CMaze(QObject *root,QQmlApplicationEngine *engine)
{
    this->root = root;
    this->engine = engine;
    /* + Some other functionality*/
}
void CMaze::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "resize event entered"; // NEVER WRITTEN to CONSOLE WHEN RESIZING 
}
```

**EDIT:**

main.qml:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("The Maze")

    Rectangle{
        id: background
        objectName: "background"
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#ffffcc"
    }
}
```

Comment: At first, don't forget `Q_OBJECT` macro in the `CMaze` declaration. At second, try `override` (only since C++11) keyword on `resizeEvent`: didn't you make a mistake?

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior is still the same, with ```Q_OBJECT``` macro and added ```override``` keyword.

Comment: @ilotXXI: he doesn't need `Q_OBJECT` here.

Comment: Make `resizeEvent` `protected` instead of `private`. It's odd that this even compiles.

Comment: Also, remove `class` from `class CMaze maze(root,&engine);` and call `maze.show()` before `app.exec()`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, after added ```maze.show()``` it is opening second blank window.

Comment: @wair92: do you call `show` in the `CMaze` constructor? Anyway, that doesn't matter. Remove the second `show` call, and try resizing the window. Perhaps, `resizeEvent` is not called when the windows shows up for the first time but only when it is actually resized.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, No, I am calling ```maze.show()``` just in the ```main``` function, just before ```return app.ecec()``` line. In CMaze class I am not calling ```show()``` method anywhere. Resizing now works, but only with a wrong blank window which was created by ```maze.show()```.

Comment: What is the content of your qml files? Do you declare a Window? Your QML isn't associated with the QWindow you declare in your snippet. You should take a look on [QQuickView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickview.html)

Comment: @wasthishelpful I edited the post with ```QML``` file

Comment: @wair92: You state "Resizing now works, but only with a wrong blank window which was created by maze.show()".  But that's *exactly* what should happen -- `CMaze` is the class in which you override the `resizeEvent` member.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, I see it now. But I still do not have an idea, how to implement ```resizeEvent``` or something silimar for a ```QML``` defined window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring 2 windows: the QWindow in the C++ code (the one you're calling the "wrong" window) which is totally unrelated to your QML, and the ApplicationWindow in your QML which has no resize handler. You should merge these 2 windows. I suggest you the following refactoring, based on the class [QQuickView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickview.html) which is a window with an integrated QML engine:

CMaze.h:

```
class CMaze: public QQuickView
{
public:
    /* QQuickView already has a QML engine and a root object */
    CMaze(/*QObject *root, QQmlApplicationEngine *engine*/);
private:
    // QObject *root;
    // QQmlApplicationEngine *engine;

    /*+ Some other variables*/

protected: /* respect inherited scope */
    /* use override to prevent misdeclaration*/
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;
```

};

CMaze.cpp:

```
CMaze::CMaze(/*QObject *root,QQmlApplicationEngine *engine*/)
{
    //this->root = root; /* replaced by this->rootObject() */
    //this->engine = engine; /* replaced by this->engine() */

    /* + Some other functionality*/
}
void CMaze::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "resize event entered";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    // QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    // engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    // QObject *root = engine.rootObjects().first();
    CMaze maze; //(root,&engine);
    /* set QML source on maze */
    maze.setSource(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    /* show the view */
    maze.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
// you already have the window: just keep the rectangle
Rectangle{
    id: background
    objectName: "background"
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "#ffffcc"
}
```